# Making realistic mold (fungus) in blender?

Tags: modeling, materials, light, lighting

so i have been trying to make realistic mold in blender for quite a while, as seen in the image the approach i've taken is making 2 image planes, one with a blurred white fur like texture to simulate the actual mold and one meant to look like mold stalks. both applied as a particle system, my main problem is the mold looks so flat, and the shadows dont really catch. does anybody have any tips for how to improve it? of if you feel that there may be a better way to simulate this please comment, i'm kinda stuck as to how to improve this so any advice helps[image: Moldy lemon, basic texture with subsurf and bumpmap]

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest adding a hair particle system to the fruit.  After all, fungus looks very much like white hair.  If you turn on children and set it to interpolated, you can clump up the hairs and change other settings to make it more random and realistic.

[image]